# Why use arrays of shape (x,) rather than (x,1)?

Tags: python, numpy

I've recently encountered a couple of bugs due to numpy arrays being in the shape (x,) - these can easily be fixed by the snippet below

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]) #this form produced a bug
a.shape 
>>> (4,)  
a.shape = [4,1] #but this change fixed it
```

But it does make me wonder, why is (x,) the default shape for 1D arrays?

Comment: 1D arrays are supposed to be 1-dimensional, but `(x, 1)` or `(1, x)` are 2D arrays. They have two dimensions, one of them set to 1. Can you be more specific in what type of bug you encounter? I suspect these bugs might actually be features :)

Comment: Better fix the bug where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each item in `shape`'s tuple denotes an axis. When you have one item in it means your array is 1 dimensional (1 axis) otherwise it will be a 2D array. When you do `a.shape = [4,1]` you're simply converting your 1D array to 2D:

```
In [26]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
In [27]: a.shape = [4,1]

In [28]: a.shape        
Out[28]: (4, 1)

In [29]: a
Out[29]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Comment: The 'wordy' display of the (4,1) array is a good reason not to make it the default for 'vectors'.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this question is coming up because you have come from a Matlab background in which everything is treated as a matrix.  In Matlab all 1D data sets are treated either as a row or a column vector and the indexing is short-circuited so that specifying a single index treats both as 1D lists.

Numpy does not deal with matrices, per se, but rather with nested lists.  Lists of lists have a similar interpretation to the matrices of Matlab, but there are key differences.  For instance, Numpy will not make any assumptions about which element you mean if you only give it a single index, the indexing always acts the same regardless of the depth of the nested lists.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(arr)
>> [1 2 3 4]
print(arr[0])
>> 1

arr.shape = [4, 1]
print(arr)
>> [[1]
>>  [2]
>>  [3]
>>  [4]]
print(arr[0])
>> [1]

arr.shape = [1, 4]
print(arr)
>> [[1 2 3 4]]
print(arr[0])
>> [1 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the documentation:

> **shape : tuple of ints**
>      The elements of the shape tuple give the lengths of the
>       corresponding array dimensions.

So, when you have the shape like `(4, )` it means that its first dimension has 4 elements in it. It makes sense right as from your example?

On the contrary, if we have the shape, as you say, as `(4, 1)`, then it means that first dimension (axis=1, in NumPy lingo) has 4 elements and second dimension (in NumPy lingo, axis=0) has 1 element in it which is not the case (for 1D arrays)